# Echo a string with no spaces using PHP

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop with list of links, and I'm trying to remove the spaces in the strings because I'll be using it as an href. So far, I successfully removed the spaces, but the code I wrote made a wide space before the string. Here's my foreach loop

```
 <ul class="list grid effect-6" id="grid">
  <?php foreach ($ppmtenants as $ppmtenant): ?> 
         <li><span class="tenant"><a href="<?php echo $this->getURL() ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?tenants=<?php echo $ppmtenant['value'] ?>"><?php echo $ppmtenant['label'] ?></a><a href="<?php echo $this->getURL() ?>?___store=
    <?php 
    $ppmtenantnospace = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$ppmtenant['label']);
    echo strtolower($ppmtenantnospace); 
    ?>"></a></span></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
```

And below is what I did to remove the spaces. I used preg_replace. Now, the spaces are gone, but it has a wide space before the string.

```
 <?php 
    $ppmtenantnospace = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$ppmtenant['label']);
    echo strtolower($ppmtenantnospace); 
    ?>
```

Live example here: http://powerplantv2.jehzlau.net/brands.
Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOckc.png

As you can see, if you hover on the images, there's an unwanted space after the ?. There should be no space so that my permalinks will work. If that space disappears, my problem will be solved. But I don't know how to make it disappear. I hope a php expert here can help me. :(

Comment: I would format the string before you do the concatenation (mainly for readability, but it may solve your question)

Comment: trim the result of the preg_replace. However, the examples you provided have no "catalogsearch/advanced/result/" in them.

Comment: Thanks! It was already solved. Now I feel so dumb. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is comming from the spaces in your html. To fix, simply move the variable declaration of `$ppmtenantnospace` above the li output, then echo it in at the correct place:

```
<ul class="list grid effect-6" id="grid">
    <?php foreach ($ppmtenants as $ppmtenant): 

        $ppmtenantnospace = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$ppmtenant['label']);?>

        <li><span class="tenant"><a href="<?php echo $this->getURL() ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?tenants=<?php echo $ppmtenant['value'] ?>"><?php echo $ppmtenant['label'] ?></a><a href="<?php echo $this->getURL() ?>?___store=<?php echo $ppmtenantnospace;?>"></a></span></li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Oh I thought antoine was the first one, but you're the first so I'll accept your answer. :D Thanks for the tip! :D

Answer (score 2):

The whitespace is actually in your HTML code
You should open the php tag right after `=`

```
<ul class="list grid effect-6" id="grid">
  <?php foreach ($ppmtenants as $ppmtenant): ?> 
         <li><span class="tenant"><a href="<?php echo $this->getURL() ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?tenants=<?php echo $ppmtenant['value'] ?>"><?php echo $ppmtenant['label'] ?></a><a href="<?php echo $this->getURL() ?>?___store=<?php 
    $ppmtenantnospace = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$ppmtenant['label']);
    echo strtolower($ppmtenantnospace); 
    ?>"></a></span></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds, damn :P

Comment: wow that solved my problem. But I'll accept user574632's answer because he's the first one to give the tip. I never thought that the solution is right in front of me. Hahaha! Thanks again. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the PHP tag before the newline in your Code

```
<ul class="list grid effect-6" id="grid">
  <?php foreach ($ppmtenants as $ppmtenant): ?> 
     <li><span class="tenant"><a href="<?php echo $this->getURL() ?>catalogsearch/advanced/result/?tenants=<?php echo $ppmtenant['value'] ?>"><?php echo $ppmtenant['label'] ?></a><a href="<?php echo $this->getURL() ?>?___store=<?php 

     $ppmtenantnospace = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$ppmtenant['label']);
     echo strtolower($ppmtenantnospace); 
     ?>"></a></span></li>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This also solved my problem. But I'll accept user574632's answer because he's the first one to give the tip. I never thought that the solution is right in front of me. Hahaha! Thanks Dragony. :D

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to stick your `<?php` to your `?___store=`? because the 4 spaces before the `<?php` are not ignored since they are not PHP code but HTML output

Comment: Ohhh.. wait gonna try it. hahahaha. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks! you're fast! That solved my problem in an instant. Awesome! Hahahahaha.. Now I feel so dumb. :D

Comment: you are welcome, no worries! @Dragony found it at the same time too

Comment: Hahaha... Yeah. I'm really happy with stackoverflow, everyone answers so fast. :D Thanks once more. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$spaceless_string = strtr($stringwithspaces, array(' ' => ''));
```